# getting Failed to allocate memory for custom tag binary object (930513672 elements of 1 bytes each) error

Tags: c#, imagemagick, imagick

i am uploding 1000 mb file through handeler like as  HttpFileCollection files = context.Request.Files; 
  using MagickImageCollection and getting error: "getting Failed to allocate memory for custom tag binary object (930513672 elements of 1 bytes each)".

```
    public void Convertepsto_jpg(string filetoconvert, string destination_path)
    {
        StringBuilder ext = new StringBuilder();
        ext.Append(Path.GetExtension(destination_path));
        try
        {
            using (MagickImageCollection setting = new MagickImageCollection())
            {


                using (MagickImage first = new MagickImage(filetoconvert))
                {
                    setting.Add(first);
                    // setting.Density = new Density(144, 144);
                    using (MagickImage result = setting.Mosaic())
                    {
                        result.ColorSpace = ColorSpace.RGB;
                        first.Quality = 300;
                        first.Trim();
                        first.Write(destination_path);
                        first.Dispose();
                        result.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorHandler.CatchError(ex, "Error in Convertepsto_jpg: " +filetoconvert);
            throw ex;


        }


    }
```

Comment: If it works for smaller files, I would say that your problem is that you are running at 32 bits, and at 32 bits you can't allocate 1gb of space.

Answer (score 0):

If it works for smaller files, I would say that your problem is that you are running at 32 bits, and at 32 bits you can't allocate 1gb of space. To verify if you are running at 32 bits, you can see if `IntPtr.Size == 4` (32 bits) or `IntPtr.Size == 8` (64 bits).

If you have the 64 bits ImageMagick, then you could try recompiling your program for 64 bits.

Comment: we are using Magick.NET-Q16-AnyCPU.dll

Comment: @user1089303 And is your app running at 64 bits?

Comment: application running set platform target->Any CPU

Comment: @user1089303 That is irrelevant. `IntPtr.Size` or `Environment.Is64BitProcess` are the only things that count.

Comment: when i am using Environment.Is64BitProcess in my code for debugging. i'm getting:- x86

Comment: @user1089303 So I had to ask you three times to discover what I already suspected. Right click on the project, Properties, Build, verify that "Prefer 32-bit" is **unselected**. If it is **unselected** then there is some dll that is forcing the 32 bitness. Try forcing the program to run at 64 bits (select as the platform target x64), It will probably tell you which dll is incompatible

Comment: i selected the target x64 . but  Getting same  error : "Failed to allocate memory for custom tag binary object (930513672 elements of 1 bytes each).  @ error/tiff.c/TIFFErrors/572".

Comment: @user1089303 Then if even at x64 it doesn't run then the problem is elsewhere

Comment: i'm getting error:-binary object (930513672 elements of 1 bytes each). `D:\Web Sites\ADBUILDER\DEMO\DEV\Images\client\DEMO\Asset/tif_220317080641.tif' @ error/tiff.c/TIFFErrors/572 

File and Method Name:    at ImageMagick.NativeInstance.CheckException(IntPtr exception, IntPtr result)
   at ImageMagick.MagickImage.NativeMagickImage.ReadFile(MagickSettings settings)
   at ImageMagick.MagickImage.Read(String fileName, MagickReadSettings readSettings, Boolean ping)
   at ImageMagick.MagickImage..ctor(String fileName)